# Can I add a bootstrap modal to an event listener?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to add a bootstrap modal to an even listener. Essentially, I am trying to make my event listener listener for a click anywhere on a page and then display a modal. Is it even possible? I don’t know what the function should look like for this..

Comment: yes, assuming your extension is permissioned for Bootstrap, the see this documentation [Bootstrap 5 Modal events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/modal/#events)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using JQuery:

```
$(document).click({
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
})
```